# How to set the center of gravity to the center of the screen in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am new in Swift Programming and I am using SpriteKit.

Is there anybody knows how to set the gravity of the world to the center of the screen which all my sprites will fall to the center of the screen?
Or is it possible to configure it? Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29615651/312594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) for this purpose

Code example

```
// create grav field
let field = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField();
// center on X-axis
field.position.x = size.width/2;
// center on Y-axis
field.position.y = size.height/2; 
// add to your world
addChild(field);
```

Comment: Hello Sir @user2893289! Thank you for answering my question. I already used that code, and set this code self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0). My concern is, can I set a new gravity weight even though I used the Example code and set the code I mentioned? 

And also, this code doesn't work "self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false" when I use the Example code.

I hope you understand my concern.